# How to refer to people you recently met

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

How to refer to people you recently met (names have been introduced and a short discussion made).
We can't possibly call them friends, can we?

```
He raises his eyes to look at his (friends?)
```

Comment: *Rise* is intransitive, *raise* transitive. The sun rises, but ones raises questions or hopes or eyes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He raises his eyes to look at his new acquaintances?

Comment: Yep, "new acquaintance" is the term.

Answer (score 2):

If the setting is purely social, then David Garner's **new acquaintances** is just fine. There are other settings, however, where simply being introduced is all that is required to establish membership in a group, and (at least to an outsider) being new to the group is probably unimportant. Teammates, coworkers, colleagues, and co-conspirators would all seem to fit this usage.